# TOC in Mac Word 2011 not including one heading

Tags: macos, styles, microsoft-word-2011, table-of-contents

I've created a TOC that uses three levels/styles: Title, Heading 1, Heading 2.  Most of the TOC is Heading 1 (page titles), but one page is missing.  I've checked and rechecked, and the appropriate line of text uses the Heading 1 style, but it refuses to join the TOC no matter how many times I update the entire TOC.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: I have had this happen on several occasions and never identified the cause. I am usually able to correct the problem though.  Try this:  Select the entire line of text on the that is not working properly. Under the Styles ribbon, click normal. Save the document. Close Word. Reopen the document. Select the line of text and change it to the Heading you want under the Styles ribbon. Update the TOC.  Let us know if you have any success.  Good Luck.  Not posted as an answer because there are too many possible causes of the problem.

Comment: OSol1tair3, your solution worked.  The strange thing is that once that page was in the TOC, the next one dropped out.  I tried the same procedure, but I couldn't choose Normal - I could choose any other style except Normal.  so I made it Strong, saved, closed, opened up again, put it back to Heading 1, and luckily it reappeared in the TOC and didn't drop any others.  I was afraid I'd have an endless cycle...  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this happen on several occasions and never identified the cause. I am usually able to correct the problem though.

Try this:

1. Select the entire line of text on the that is not working properly.
2. Under the Styles ribbon, click normal.
3. Save the document.
4. Close Word.
5. Reopen the document.
6. Select the line of text and change it to the Heading you want under the Styles ribbon.
7. Update the TOC.